# Error 400 with Stripe iOS Payment

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Stripe to process payments in my iOS Swift app and Firebase Cloud Functions for the backend. I setup an example app using Stripe's Example project located here:

[Stripe iOS Standard Integration](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift))

When I load the CheckoutView I get an Error 400 response. The issue I believe is with the backendURL that I set in CheckoutViewController (customized using the link to the example above):

```
// 2) Next, optionally, to have this demo save your user's payment details, head to
    // https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend/tree/v13.0.3, click "Deploy to Heroku", and follow
    // the instructions (don't worry, it's free). Replace nil on the line below with your
    // Heroku URL (it looks like https://blazing-sunrise-1234.herokuapp.com ).
    let backendBaseURL: String? = "https://us-central1-app-1253c.cloudfunctions.net/https-client-donateToUser"
```

I get the following messages in my Cloud Function logs:

`Request has incorrect Content-Type. application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
`Invalid request IncomingMessage`
`Function execution took 498 ms, finished with status code: 400`

I tried using the URL of the actual Firebase app (ex: appname123.firebaseapp.com) but that returns an Error 404 instead.

Any ideas for a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @psmvac I fixed the backend URL. However, I'm now getting error `The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format`. I believe this is because I don't have a cloud function to accept ephemeral keys. This is what I have so far, what else does this need in order to match the iOS Stripe Example? I'm struggling to find any Cloud Function examples of this online.

```
export const ephemeral_keys = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const stripe_version = data.api_version

    stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(data.customer_id,stripe_version)
    }
)
```

Comment: Which class is used to send request? Is it NSURLSession or Alamofire framework?

Comment: Set the content type to JSON in the header configuration before sending the request.

Comment: If you're using the Stripe iOS Standard Integration Example, the APIClient client implementation should be [using AlamoFire and should be sending urlencoded](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)/MyAPIClient.swift#L49-L61) parameters (with Content type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as you saw). You would need to make sure that your Cloud Function [parses the parameters accordingly](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests), e.g `request.body.api_version` in the case of your `ephemeral_keys` function.

Comment: Also in the snippet you posted you are using as the value of your `backendBaseURL` what I understand being the full path to your Google Cloud Function. Note that if you use the Stripe iOS Standard Integration Example this value should be the base of your backend and the path to the actual endpoint, or in your case, to your GC function would be appended in the particular method of the APIClient. e.g `ephemeral_keys` path [is appended here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)/MyAPIClient.swift#L49).

Comment: so say you have a GC function named `ephemeral_keys` (for handling request from your app to fetch the [Ephemeral Key](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard#prepare-your-api)) and can be triggered for example via the URL: `https://us-central1-app-1253c.cloudfunctions.net/ephemeral_keys`

Comment: then you would want to have `backendBaseURL` set to `https://us-central1-app-1253c.cloudfunctions.net` and leave the [`ephemeral_keys` path to be appended](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)/MyAPIClient.swift#L49) by the specific method of your APIClient.

Comment: @psmvac thanks for the replies! Sorry I didn't get a chance to look at this sooner. I changed backendURL to just `https://us-central1-app-1253c.cloudfunctions.net` but now I'm getting error `The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format`. Currently looking into this. Any ideas? Feel like I'm getting closer thanks to you

Comment: I think part of the problem is that I don't have an ephemeral keys Cloud Function. Do you know where I can find example code?

Comment: @winston: for the new error that you are getting, I suggest making sure that your Cloud Function return as a JSON response the object that you get from the API call as is. I don't think there is a GCF example but I'd suggest taking at the Node example in this doc to see how the body of the function should do:
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard#prepare-your-api

Comment: @psmvac I'll look into it, thanks again for the help! Feel free to make an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: @winston Did you end up with a working solution? I'm struggling to find a way of doing this. Thank you very much!